# How can I write junit test cases for IBM Portlets created using JSR-286?

Tags: java, junit, portlet, websphere-portal

I have created a simple portlet(JSR-286) using IBM Rational Application Developer 9.0 . I would like to write a junit test cases for the same. I have followed the steps provided on the link : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/wa-portletunit/index.html
but I could not succeed , getting null pointer exception.
Here is the code snippet:

```
public void testdoViewOfGenericBookmarkWithPortletUnit() throws Exception
{
    PortletRunner runner = getPortletRunner();
    PortletUser user = new GenericPortletUser();
    runner.setUser(user);
    WebResponse bookmarkResponse=runner.getResponse();

    WebLink[] links=bookmarkResponse.getLinks();
    assertEquals(links.length,1);
    assertEquals(links[0].getText(),"IBM");

}

private PortletRunner getPortletRunner() throws Exception {
    File webInfDir=new File("/home/akshay/rad_workspace/MyPortal/WebContent");
    Class portletClass = MyPortalPortlet.class;
    PortletRunner runner = PortletRunner.createPortletRunner(portletClass,webInfDir,    
"MyPortal");
return runner;
}
```

The problem is at line where we get PortletRunner instance in getPortletRunner method, error stack-trace as below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.pluto.portalImpl.services.config.Config.getParameters(Config.java:40)
    at net.sf.portletunit.servlet.PortletUnitServlet.init(PortletUnitServlet.java:115)
    at com.meterware.servletunit.WebApplication$ServletConfiguration.getServlet(WebApplication.java:587)
    at com.meterware.servletunit.WebApplication$ServletRequestImpl.getServlet(WebApplication.java:775)
    at com.meterware.servletunit.InvocationContextImpl$ExecutionContext.getServlet(InvocationContextImpl.java:251)
    at com.meterware.servletunit.InvocationContextImpl.getServlet(InvocationContextImpl.java:89)
    at net.sf.portletunit.PortletRunner.initializePluto(PortletRunner.java:258)
    at net.sf.portletunit.PortletRunner.<init>(PortletRunner.java:91)
    at net.sf.portletunit.PortletRunner.createPortletRunner(PortletRunner.java:296)
    at com.ibm.portletunit.bookmarktest.test.BookmarkExampletest.getPortletRunner(BookmarkExampletest.java:92)
    at com.ibm.portletunit.bookmarktest.test.BookmarkExampletest.testdoViewOfGenericBookmarkWithPortletUnit(BookmarkExampletest.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Please, can anybody help me here.I have a doubt that portletunit does not support JSR-286.
Also what other libraries available for junit testing of portlet(JSR-286) build using  IBM Rational Application Developer 9.0

Comment: The article you linked specifically says "portletUnit is a Java™ Unit (JUnit) Testing framework for testing JSR-168 portlets". The comments on the article don't give any explicit statement that JSR-286 portlets are supported.